# How to wipe out data on a USB drive that is faulty, so that data can't be recovered?

Tags: deletion, usb-drive

I have several faulty USB drives and I like to return these to the vendor to get my money back - but without the vendor being able to access any data which might be still on the drives

Problem is, the USB drives won't allow me to access the data, so I can't format the drive, I can't wipe out data and I can't copy or delete data, but the data is still there. I checked the data being there with many programs and computers in both Linux and Windows. I also tried to format, delete, copy and wipe out data in both Linux and Windows. I don't have access to it. Many times I get input/output errors, which errors I think are hardware built by the factory, which they can probably bypass with some of their own hardware.

My question is, how to wipe out data on a USB drive, so not even recovery program can recover it. I don't care, if I have to electrocute it with electricity, as long as it stays visually intact.

Comment: I've reduced your question to the relevant facts. No matter how you feel about the vendor - this site is not the place for accusations.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, how to wipe out data on a USB drive, so not even recovery program can recover it. I don't care, if I have to electrocute it with electricity, as long as it stays visually intact.

You likely can't with software methods. The flash chip is normally separate from the controller, which talks USB. You don't know which part is broken, only that the controller refuses you to talk to the flash for some reason.

If you remove the flash chip from the board, you may be able to read or write data. This is a fairly destructive process, which will likely void any warranties that was ever there.

If secrecy is important, I'd smash up the flash chip with a hammer. This will make recovery very difficult. If you manage to smash the die inside the chip as well it will require very special equipment. But again, no sane manufacturer will honor their warranty if you return a physically smashed drive.

In the future, encrypt data. Then you won't have to worry about destroying it.

Comment: I normally encrypt my disks, but i wanted to use the USB disk on Windows and Linux with ease, else I would buy something else than a flash drive anyway. Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: VeraCrypt works in all major OSes.

Comment: "as long as it stays visually intact" - this precludes any smashing

Comment: you didn't answer his question, not like you could have done with the limited info on the OP. I think most people are aware they can smash stuff with a hammer.

Comment: @Coderxyz *You can't* is an answer, albeit not the one the author wants.

Comment: It depends if the vendor wants back a device they can run diagnostics on, or if they just want the device back sufficiently intact that they can determine you didn't resell it.  At some level, "hammer" is really the best answer to prevent data from being retrieved from a discarded flash.